# how to filter AGE based on condition if my age column is like below

Tags: hive

this is the data given.

```
Sample_Size Age(years)
    7304    
    2581    
    4723    
    1153    
    2402    
    1925    
    1812    
    356     18 - 24
    598     25 - 34
    865     35 - 44
    1288    45 - 54
    1676    55 - 64
    2521    65 or older
```

**he asked me to Filter the data based on `Sample_Size` more than 1000 and `Age(years)` between `40 to 50`**

what i did is,
i created table.dumped the csv file into that hive table .now i need to filter the data according to given condition.

which logic should I apply to filter the column?

Comment: Please edit the question and show your expected output. Also let us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: i have edited the data

Comment: pls show us only Sample_Size and Age(years) columns. I don't see any issue on the data